# C++ Visual Studio - Regex Whitespaces

Tags: c++, regex

I'm having trouble with whitespaces on this topic, can someone help me out?

```
int main() {

    string test;

    regex foo("Daniel\s[[:w:]]+");

    cout << "Test me" << endl;
    cin >> test;

    bool result= regex_match(test, foo);
    cout << (result? "Match" : "No Match") << endl;
}
```

Im trying to get Daniel "Last Name", but it just won't take the whitespace.I also tried [[:spaces:]] but no luck. Any ideas?

I'm using VS Community

Comment: I got my input with getline(cin, test) and it worked !

Comment: `regex foo("Daniel\\s[[:w:]]+");` or `regex foo(R"(Daniel\s[[:w:]]+)");`

Comment: @DanielAvila so was the problem "cin"? Because I am having the same problem atm ..